# Cannot use groupBy to filter on a navigation property on a linq query

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a class with a navigation property, like this:

```
class RoleUser {
    ... //some properties
    Role Role {get;set;}
}
```

where a `Role` can have multiple `RoleUsers`, so

```
class Role {
    ... //some properties
    string IdRole {get;set;}
    ICollection<RoleUser> RoleUsers {get;set;}
}
```

In my DB a user of a specific sector can be present multiple times due to other properies making some other differences. I want to perform a query using Linq to get only the users belonging on Distinct Role. I tried using `GroupBy`, but without success. My query is:

```
return repository.Query(r => r.Account == string.Concat(domain, "\\", userName))
                .Include(i=>i.Role)
                .Select()
                .AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(g=>new {Role = g})
                .Select(s => s.Key.Role)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Why do you use `GroupBy` for filtering? You should use: `.Where(x => x.Role.IdRole == "DesiredRoleId")`

Comment: Because a user can be in roleA and roleB multiple times, but I want to get only one user for each different role.

Comment: @MarcoMascii What are you trying to get back, a list of users, a list of roles, or something else?

Comment: Do you have a User entity? Does RoleUser entity contains reference to the User?

Comment: I trying to get back a list of users

Comment: @MarcoMascii Would you like to get back a list of all users, or only users who hold a single role? If you'd like to get all users, along with a role attached to them, which of potentially several roles are you trying to get back?

Comment: @MarcoMascii a small example of the output that you need would help make things clearer

Comment: GroupBy(g=>new {Role = g}) doesn't seem to be right.